# Attacking BLE device as third party, is it possible?

Tags: android, security, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Recently I'm playing with a security key card which is using BLE to communicate with phones. So, I was thinking if I can hack this card remotely without needing to pair with it.

I knew that BLE is a peer-to-peer protocol and it uses LTK(long-term key) to tell if both are connected before.

Plus, after some reverse engineering, I believe the key card also stores paired phone's Bluetooth address for authentication purpose.

So, provided I know these things:

1. LTK used by the card and legit phone. (Can be cracked using a BLE sniffer and software)

2. Bluetooth address of the legit phone.

3. The handle and command to communicate with the key card.


Is it possible for me to pretend myself as the legit phone and send  malicious command to get keys inside the card?

Even though I may not be able to get the data response directly (For there will be two BT device with the same address), maybe I could still sniff it from the air?

Comment: Assuming that the card uses an asymmetric key cipher with sufficiently large keys you should not be able to determine the private key through probing the card and its public key is, well, public.  If the card doesn't use that approach, then who knows?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank for commenting. That's actually my other question in mind. Yes it's using asymmetric key cipher (ECDH). But a small card like it is apparently not capable to do every decryption inside it, so I assume it still have to give it's companion app the private key at some time and let the phone do the heavy job.... well of course these are all guesses.

Comment: After checking the log of companion app, I can only be sure that the card will send some kind of "session data" and the app will call a function named [NativeECCryptoProvider : ECDH_ComputeFullSharedSecret] and then generate a pair of Ze and Zs.

Comment: Ok, so it is using [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie–Hellman) to generate a shared session key.  Unless you can obtain the private key of the card and the phone then you cannot generate the same shared key.  Of course, the more data you intercept the greater your chance of determining the shared key through brute force attacks; Particularly if some or all of the plaintext is known by the attacker

Comment: @Paulw11 So maybe the only use of the card is to authenticate and open the app....  Because the app can even encrypt VoIP calls, but a card surely isn't powerful enough to decrypt such large data in real time. Anyway, I really appreciate your insight of key cards operation :D

Comment: Yes, the card is just a credential.  It simply needs to deliver some sort of identity data (probably in the order of 256 bits or maybe even less).  The phone probably generates a random nonce that is manipulated by the card and returned.   Since the payload is random and changes each time the chance of deriving the key is small.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much! You just cleared my mindflow that's stuck for so long. I hate that I can't up vote you in comments ='(